# Why should two equal power series have identical coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Assume that $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}, \quad g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_{i}x^{i}, \quad f(x) = g(x)$ for $|x| < r$, $r > 0$.

> Why does $f(x)=g(x)$ imply $a_{0}=b_{0},\text{ } a_{1}=b_{1},\text{ }...$?

Comment: In what sense do the series converge? Have you made an attempt? To answer this question we have to know what you know about power series.

Comment: Another point not mentioned in the answer is linear independence. As monomials $x^n, x^m$ are linearly independent if $n \neq m$, there is no such constants $c_1,c_2$ that $c_1 x^n+c_2 x^m=0$ for any uncountable set of $x$. From this property the result for (absolutely convergent) power series immediately follows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a_0 = f(0) = g(0) = b_0,$$
$$a_1 = f'(0) = g'(0) = b_1,$$
$$\cdots$$
Can you continue?